# Como fazer um elemento sumir depois de usado?

Tags: c#, winforms

Como fazer um elemento sumir depois de usado por exemplo :

> Ao clicar em um button ele sumir e surgir algo como uma ListBox?

Ps1 : Se a pergunta estiver confusa avisar

Ps2 : Se puderem dizer oque fazer para o button voltar aparecer ajuda muito

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar os métodos [**`Hide()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide(v=vs.110).aspx) e [**`Show()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show(v=vs.110).aspx) dos seus elementos para esconder e exibir respectivamente.

```
button1.Hide(); //Esconde o Botão
button1.Show(); //Exibe o Botão
```

Isto pode ser utilizado também para outros componentes gráficos que você desejar

```
label1.Hide();
listBox1.Hide();
```

Portando, basta adicionar os códigos na sequencia de ações que desejar, como no exemplo citado por você:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Hide(); //Esconde o Botão
    listBox1.Show(); //Exibe o ListBox
}
```